# Elastic query for relevant data

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance

From the below, candidate Data structure How to write a query for getting records for the query candidate must have java experience > 1 and SQL experience > 2 and good to have angular experience > 1 but not must. Is it possible with the below data structure or if not how to structure that data

```
//Cand - 1
 { 
   "canId": 1,
   "skill": "Java",
   "yearsOfExp": 2
 },
 {
   "canId":1,
   "skill": "SQL",
   "yearsOfExp": 1
 },
 {
   "canId": 1,
   "skill": "Angular",
   "yearsOfExp": 1
 },
 {
   "canId": 1,
   "skill": "AngularJS",
   "yearsOfExp": 1
 }
 
 //Cand - 2
 { 
   "canId": 2,
   "skill": "Jr.Software Developer",
   "yearsOfExp": 3
 },
 {
   "canId":2,
   "skill": "SQL",
   "yearsOfExp": 2
 },
 {
   "canId": 2,
   "skill": "Angular",
   "yearsOfExp": 2
 },
 {
   "canId": 2,
   "skill": "AngularJS",
   "yearsOfExp": 5
 }
```

Comment: show your mappings

Comment: I didn't configure any mppings

Comment: @Ramakrishna Reddy did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: @Bhavya It's working, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy glad this worked for you! Thank u for accepting my answer 

Comment: @Bhavya Is it possible to apply some weightage on years of experience to show the most experienced on top with most matching skills

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy I am not sure, but it may be achieved via function score in a nested query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to structure that data

Have modified the structure of data, and indexed the data (in the form of nested document). The [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) is a specialized version of the object data type that allows arrays of objects to be indexed in a way that they can be queried independently of each other.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "canId": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "skill": "Java",
      "yearsOfExp": 2
    },
    {
      "skill": "SQL",
      "yearsOfExp": 3
    },
    {
      "skill": "Angular",
      "yearsOfExp": 2
    },
    {
      "skill": "AngularJS",
      "yearsOfExp": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "data.skill": "Java"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "filter": {
                  "script": {
                    "script": {
                      "source": "doc['data.yearsOfExp'].value > 1",
                      "lang": "painless"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "data.skill": "SQL"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "filter": {
                  "script": {
                    "script": {
                      "source": "doc['data.yearsOfExp'].value > 2",
                      "lang": "painless"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "data",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "data.skill": "Angular"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "filter": {
                "script": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": "doc['data.yearsOfExp'].value > 1",
                    "lang": "painless"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64339149",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3.6119184,
        "_source": {
          "canId": 1,
          "data": [
            {
              "skill": "Java",
              "yearsOfExp": 2
            },
            {
              "skill": "SQL",
              "yearsOfExp": 3
            },
            {
              "skill": "Angular",
              "yearsOfExp": 2
            },
            {
              "skill": "AngularJS",
              "yearsOfExp": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```